# What is the composition of transaction types in current blocks?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, p2sh, p2pkh

What types of transactions do we see in blocks today and how much of the blockspace do they occupy?

I.e. does someone have data how much of the blocks are `Pay to PubKey Hash`, `Pay to PubKey`, `Pay to Script Hash`,…?

I've found [A survey of Bitcoin Transaction Types](http://www.quantabytes.com/articles/a-survey-of-bitcoin-transaction-types), but it's from April 2014 and outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had the same question and made a small script to compute it (using [this python library](https://github.com/alecalve/python-bitcoin-blockchain-parser)). Here you have a cumulative plot showing the number of transaction outputs of each kind over time:

[image: Cumulative plot of the number of transaction outputs per type]

Comment: Thanks, very cool. Would that script be available somewhere or the image perhaps even dynamically updated in the web somewhere? 0:-)